# Controlling child process window size in Python

Tags: python, wxwidgets, gtk3

I have a Gtk 3 application written in Python.  I'd like to start a child process which I haven't written but which I know creates a single main window, and put it in a specific place on the screen with a specific size.

The child application uses wxWidgets, in case that makes a difference.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 (and therefore using Wayland) but the solution should also work under X11 and, ideally, win32 and macosx.

**Edit** Since it seems some people don't understand the question, I'll rephrase it:  How can I control the window placement of a child process's window in Python, at least on Wayland/Ubuntu but preferably in a way that also works on win32 and macosx?  The child process is written by someone other than me (though is open source) and uses wxWidgets.

Comment: so what is your question exactly?

Comment: If you are using WxWidgets, why do you have a Gtk3 tag?

Comment: @theGtknerd - did you read the question?  I am not using wxWidgets.  I am using Gtk.  I want my Gtk application to position another application that it starts as a child process and that application uses wxWidgets.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Gtk part. I was mostly reading about what you want to do, not about what is working.

Answer (score -1):

In wxWidgets, every window (and a control is a window) can be set to a position and a size at its constructor.

For an existing wxWindow you can call `Move()` or `SetPosition()`